# SSO between Salesforce - Mobile app - web service provider

Tags: single-sign-on, mobilesdk, saml

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to maintain a SSO session between 3 different elements:

- Mobile APP (Android/IOS) - developed with Salesforce SDK
- Salesforce (Identity provider)
- Web service provider (Web application)

The SSO to implement is considered to be the federated authentication with SAML, with Salesforce (community) configured as identity provider.

I couldn't find clear documentation on how authentication starts and can it be maintained on the mobile app, and then switch context from mobile app to a web service provider.

**I'm considering the following use case:**

a) User authenticated in mobile app (Andoid/IOS) - as I understood, this is done via OAuth2, as SAML doesn't seem to support natively the mobile app.

b) from mobile the used is sent to SP (Service provider)

- b.1) through webview
- b.2) or switching on browser

Is it possible to implement SSO SAML on Salesforce, so we can maintain the authentication and don't ask again the credentials to the user?

Is there any documentation on how to implement an equivalent use case? Can this be done via standard capabilities of SDK and Salesforce SSO SAML?

**EDIT----- 20200110 13:09**

Researching a bit more, I found this article
[Configuring SSO for Mobile and Desktop Apps Using SAML and OAuth](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_mobileDT_saml_n_oauth.htm)
which is somehow clear in the high level, but not so much on how to do so.

Furthermore, I'm getting confused by the indication "Salesforce org configured as a service provider" (first sentence from the section "App Support for SSO").

Is there any demo/documentation regarding this? Is this applicable to my question?

Comment: I think that you're missing an important point about SSO: it only works on the same machine. You can't switch from mobile to desktop and keep the same session.

Comment: @POZ thanks for to take time and analyse my question. 

Sorry, maybe my wording is confusing, actually I don't want to change Machine/Hardware. The use case is such that the user is using a native mobile app (where he is authenticated/authorized) and he requests from the mobile app (click tap) a page/url that is served by a web application (which may be opened/served to user by a webview or switching the application to the browser. I would like to maintain the user still authenticated/authorized on the web app.